How to cast unifex::task as an type erase sender
I have a function that create a async task: virtual unifex::any_sender_of<int> get_data(). And I try to use coroutine to simplify the implement. But unifex::task<int> can not cast to unifex::any_sender_of<int>. What's missing here?
Here is a minimal reproduction: https://godbolt.org/z/q6nqedoxE
